# Azure Active Directory + spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I am trying to run the azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample but it is not working. After opening localhost:8080 it prompts with the localhost:8080/login page and Azure link. After clicking on it it goes to the Azure Active Directory page. After successful login it comes back to the /login page rather than the /welcome page. I tried using other examples as well available on the internet but nothing seems to be working. Please advise.

Comment: Can you link the code sample you were using? You likely need to change the redirect URI your app passes in the Auth request to you /welcome page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your application under the Azure Active Directory where your users are stored. Then enter the published homepage URL in the Reply URL section in your App Registration. The Reply URL or PostLogoutRedirectURI in your config or app settings needs to match what's listed in your app registration. If it's redirecting to localhost that probably means that one or both are set to localhost. Set it to your welcome page URL (https://welcome.azurewebsites.net) in both locations and then try again.

See my [blog post](https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b) and accompanying video to see where to set this up.